# NullPointerException when trying to set a jcheckbox

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Trying to set it so if a certain condition is met then one of two check-boxes will be checked.  However I keep getting a nullpointerexception error.

the code is..

```
        //Set the flat rate or hourly billing check boxes.
    if(flatRateint > 0) {
        InvoiceUI.jCheckBox1.setSelected(true);
    }
    else {
        InvoiceUI.jCheckBox2.setSelected(true);
    }
```

The error is

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at my.freelancebillingapp.InvoiceSelectionUI.jButton1MouseClicked(InvoiceSelectionUI.java:224)
>           at my.freelancebillingapp.InvoiceSelectionUI.access$100(InvoiceSelectionUI.java:17)
>           at my.freelancebillingapp.InvoiceSelectionUI$2.mouseClicked(InvoiceSelectionUI.java:86)
>           at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:253)
>           at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6266)
>           at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
>           at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
>           at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
>           at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4247)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
>           at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
>           at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

Comment: Did you try printing some debug to see what's null?  Which line of the code you included is line 224?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming line 224 of InvoiceSelectionUI.java is included in your sample, one of the following must be null:

- `InvoiceUI`
- `InvoiceUI.jCheckBox1`
- `InvoiceUI.jCheckBox2`
- `flatRateint` (if it's an `Integer`, but not if it's an `int`)

Comment: Thanks!  Figured out I had it trying to change the selected setting before they were initialized - moved the code and it works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

I think jcheckBox[12] are static fields of InvoiceUI you didn't initialize.

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct is that `flatRateint` might be null, but from the name I'm guessing it's a primitive `int`, which would rule that out.  Your error message is about mouse clicks; so I suspect code in your `onclick()` method.  I'm no guru, but I find that errors often occur two or three lines before the location mentioned in the actual error printout.  Maybe something like

```
if(someObj.someMethod() == foo)
    flatRateint = 5;
else
    flatRateint = 8;
```

and `someObj` was never initialized?